# How do we deal with the build time data fetch vs real time data for Next.js Server Side Rendering SSR?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Since when we have a React app, if a search engine pulls our page, it is almost all empty content except mostly JavaScript code, without any content to index, so it has quite poor SEO.

So Next.js has SSR and has `getStaticProps()` to fetch data during build time.

But the data is provided to the component as `props`, while our data fetching `useEffect()` also fetches data at the client's side. So how do we handle the `props` data vs the "state" set by `setData()` of a `useState()` React Hook?

My research so far is we can do:

```js
export default function Home({ dataAtBuild }) {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://api.weather.gov/gridpoints/MTR/84,105/forecast")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((d) => setData(d));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="Home">
      <main>
        <Weather data={data || dataAtBuild} />
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const dataAtBuild = await fetch(
    "https://api.weather.gov/gridpoints/MTR/84,105/forecast"
  ).then((res) => res.json());

  return {
    props: {
      dataAtBuild
    }
  };
}
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-zhukovsky-l7wb9?file=/pages/index.js
Single page demo:  https://l7wb9.sse.codesandbox.io/

and if I do

```sh
curl https://l7wb9.sse.codesandbox.io/ | grep -o -E '.{30}Time of.{60}'
```

it is able to get the "build time data". How do we handle this build time data as props vs the data set by `setData()`?

P.S. I re-read [the Static Generation vs SSR info](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages). It actually seems like when we use `getStaticProps()`, we are supposed to build "static pages" (what is called "Static Generation"), and not supposed to fetch real time data when the user visits the page, but the code above can do that. So I am confused if it should be 100% static or not.

Comment: "... what is the standard way it should be done?" --> According to what standard??

Comment: according to the Next.js standard

Comment: Can you provide a link to the standard, please?

Comment: I do not know of the standard, so how do I "provide a link" to the standard?

Comment: Well, how can you be expected to follow a standard if you don't even have information about that standard?

Comment: I don't know something, so I ask. And you are saying when asking, I should provide a link to the answer

Comment: Your approach seems fine to me. You could look into the [SWR](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/with-nextjs#pre-rendering) library, built by the same people who did Next.js, to get an idea.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I would say either fetch it on the client or do it at build time, but as it is data which is quickly out of date, only using [Incremental Static Regeneration](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#incremental-static-regeneration):

> With getStaticProps you don't have to stop relying on dynamic content, as static content can also be dynamic. Incremental Static Regeneration allows you to update existing pages by re-rendering them in the background as traffic comes in.

So you could update your `getStaticProps` function to this:

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const dataAtBuild = await fetch(
    "https://api.weather.gov/gridpoints/MTR/84,105/forecast"
  ).then((res) => res.json());

  return {
    props: {
      dataAtBuild
    },
    // Next.js will attempt to re-generate the page:
    // - When a request comes in
    // - At most once every second
    revalidate: 1, // In seconds
  };
}
```

But using both methods seems like overkill to me and negates the increase in speed you will gain using only one of these methods.

**EDIT:**

You also can initialize your state with the fetched data. So the component would look like this:

```
export default function Home({ dataAtBuild }) {
  const [data, setData] = useState(dataAtBuild);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://api.weather.gov/gridpoints/MTR/84,105/forecast")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((d) => setData(d));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="Home">
      <main>
        <Weather data={data} />
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}
```

But still, when using `revalidate` you would not need the hook, as the data will be revalidated every second in the example and so the user should always get the most up-to-date data.

Comment: "I would say either fetch it on the client or do it at build time"... the app has to fetch the data to show something to the user, and we are doing build time data fetch so that search engines won't see a completely blank page, so what does it mean "I would say either fetch it on the client or do it at build time" ?

Comment: On the client would be using the fetch in `useEffect`, at build time would be using the fetch in `getStaticProps`.